# Al buscar un registro por id me arroja el resultado dos veces express.js

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo un problema tengo una ruta en express para seleccionar un registro mandando el id y funciona pero el probelma es que me muestra el registro dos veces, ya revise en mi base de datos para ver si tenia un registro repetido pero es imposible porque el id es llave primaria, ya revise el procedimiento almacenado y si funciona bien solo me trae el registro una vez ¿Algguna idea de cual podria ser el problema?

Conexion a la base de datos

```
const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const pool1Connect = pool1.connect();

pool1.on('error', err => {
    console.log("Sql database connection error " ,err);
})
```

Registro

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Registroid":12,
                "Name":"Rodolfo Salazar",
                "Age": 45,
                "Adress": "Del Real 405",
                "Phone": "5558200325"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
                "Registroid":12,
                "Name":"Rodolfo Salazar",
                "Age": 45,
                "Adress": "Del Real 405",
                "Phone": "5558200325"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [],
    "returnValue": 0
}
```

Ruta

```
router.get('/apirest/Registros/:id',async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const{id}=req.params;
    let result =await pool1.request()
      .input('Registroid', sql.Int, id)
      .execute('Getregistro')
      res.send(result);
  } 
    catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Este registro no existe' })
    }
});
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las llaves que salen en tu sección de "Registro" se muestran con nombre diferentes, la primera -recordsets-, la segunda -recordset-, ambas apuntan a un mismo registro pero en sí son llaves distintas, tal vez te ayude en alguna forma.

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza Gracias compañero ya investigue un poco más y es normal que haga eso la libreria mssql, no es ningun error ni se estan ejecutando dos veces alguna funcion

Comment: Si deseas enviar sólo los resultados obtenidos de la consulta, debes acceder a los elementos del `array`, por ejemplo: `result.recordset[0]` accede al primer elemento de dicho `array` llamado `recordset`. Puedes averiguar la cantidad de registros devueltos con `result.recordset.length`. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de @Mauricio Contreras, al final asi quedo mi ruta, ya no salen 2 veces los registros

```
router.get('/apirest/Registros/:id',async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const{id}=req.params;
    let result =await pool1.request()
      .input('Registroid', sql.Int, id)
      .execute('Getregistro')
      res.status(200).send({
         "registros": result.recordset.length,
          data:result.recordset});
  } 
    catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Este registro no existe' })
    }
});
```